# How do I get database data on every request?

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony 2.4 and I need to query the database on every request in order to make some configuration values available to the application, how can I do it?

Comment: Setup a kernel.request listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the listener:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/AcmeListener.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class AcmeListener
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.manager')->getRepository('repositoryName'); // load data from database
    }
}
```

Define the listener:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeListener
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Also maybe usefull to read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/mime_type.html) example